# How do I analyze this code for time and space complexity? Ideas for removing those?

Tags: python, complexity-theory

```
while True:
    try:
      income = int(input("Please enter your taxable income in india: "))
    except ValueError:
       print("Sorry, We didn't understand that please enter taxable income as a number")
       continue
    

    if income <= 250000:  #2 Lakh 50 thousand
       tax = 0
    

    elif income <= 500000: #5 Lakh
       tax = (income - 250000) * 0.05

        
    elif income <= 750000: #7 lakh 50 thousand
       tax = (income - 500000) * 0.10 + 12500
    
        
    elif income <= 1000000: #10 Lakh
       tax = (income - 750000) * 0.15 + 37500

        
    elif income <= 1250000: #12 lakh 50 thousand
       tax = (income - 1000000) * 0.20 + 75000

        
    elif income <= 1500000: #15 lakh
       tax = (income - 1250000) * 0.25 + 125000

        
    else:
       tax = (income - 1500000) * 0.30 + 187500

    print("you owe", tax, "Rupees in tax!")
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `collections.OrderedDict` + `itertools.dropwhile`? Idk newly added pattern matching can be used for such but since it's rather new feature I'm passing.

Basically this solution might even be slower than your code(if chain is quite fast than you think) but could be easier to maintain later on.

Idea is:

0. put tuple of 3 values used in calculations for corresponding tax range as key.
1. put `float("inf")` too, so we can avoid any `if` blocks. (So any number would have key larger than itself)
2. make ordered dictionary to make sure keys are in increasing order always when iterating.
3. use [`itertools.dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) with `lambda x: x <= input_num` so we skip all keys that is smaller than input.
4. Call `next()` to the `itertools.dropwhile` iterator since we are only interested in first larger number in keys.
5. unpack tuple and do the calculation

```py
>>> income_table = {
...     250000: (0, 0, 0),
...     500000: (250000, 0.05, 0),
...     750000: (500000, 0.1, 12500),
...     1000000: (750000, 0.15, 37500),
...     1250000: (1000000, 0.2, 75000),
...     1500000: (1250000, 0.25, 125000),
...     float("inf"): (1500000, 0.3, 187500),
... }
... ordered_table = OrderedDict(income_table)
... else_case = (1500000, 0.3, 187500)

>>> import itertools

>>> def check_range(input_num: int) -> float:
...     matching_ceiling = next(itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x < input_num, ordered_table.keys()))
...     subtract, multiplier, addition = income_table[matching_ceiling]
...     return (input_num - subtract) * multiplier + addition

>>> # test -------------

>>> check_range(14000)
0

>>> check_range(1000000000)
299737500.0

>>> check_range(150000)
0

>>> check_range(1500000)
187500.0

>>> check_range(2500000)
487500.0

>>> check_range(250000)
0

>>> check_range(250001)
0.05
```

---

I see you are new to the StackOverFlow, welcome! If you didn't already, please give a few minute to [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for tips and guides on StackOverFlow!